# Grok pattern for Logstash input log file

Tags: string, logstash, logstash-grok, nagios

> [1603870834] SERVICE ALERT: localhost;Swap Usage;OK;SOFT;2;SWAP OK - 1% free (0 MB out of 1023 MB)

I have to filter that string example in *JSON* format for *Logstash* it is my *Nagios* log file output that I have to load into my ELK using *Logstash*, how I can write to grok for that?

Answer (score 0):

In grok there is a dedicated pattern for this type of line : *NAGIOSLOGLINE*.

So in your case try this :

```
 filter {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{NAGIOSLOGLINE}" }
      }
    }
```

For information, you could use *grokdebug* for test more pattern [here](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: actually i am looking for the proper json formate i found something like                                   
  expected Grok Patteren --   \[%{NUMBER:unix_timestamp}\]\s%{DATA:type}:\s%{DATA:host};%{DATA:service};%{DATA:status};%{DATA:nagios_status};%{DATA:int};%{GREEDYDATA:nagios_message}.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified grok pattern of what you have find:

`\[%{NUMBER:unix_timestamp}\]\s%{DATA:type}:\s%{DATA:host};%{DATA:service};%{DATA:status};%{DATA:nagios_status};%{DATA:int};%{GREEDYDATA:nagios_message}`